# will work for a redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I can't get a javascript redirect working for nothing :(

I have a form.php with 3 options, it posts to engine.php where depending on which option is chosen will either create and download the file, email the file, or both.

If email is chosen, I can redirect easily, but when "both" is chosen, I cannot get a redirect for the life of me.  Please help.

Here is the code for engine.php

```
//if CSV selected   
if(isset($_POST['csv']) AND ($which_option == "download")) {
    @include('UPDATER-csv.download.php');
}
    elseif(isset($_POST['csv']) AND ($which_option == "email")) {
        @include('UPDATER-csv.email.php');
        @include('UPDATER-email.php');
        header('Location: http://www.calligraphydallas.com/updater/UPDATER-email.sent.php');
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['csv']) AND ($which_option == "both")) {
        @include('UPDATER-csv.both.php');
        @include('UPDATER-email.php');
        $link = "<script>window.open('http://www.calligraphydallas.com/updater/UPDATER-email.sent.php')</script>";
        echo $link;
    }
```

Why doesn't that javascript work?

Comment: `Why doesn't that javascript work?` - because it's not javascript - nevermind, just saw the single line of javascript ... `window.open` isn't how you redirect

Comment: is it trying to open a popup and the popup is being blocked? Also, typo. you need a semicolon

Comment: @JaromandaX it opens a new tab. Or, a popup in his example.

Comment: which isn't a redirect @Ice76 ... *I can't get a javascript **redirect** working*

Comment: thanks guys, for the quick replies.  @Ice76... where is the missing semicolon?  yeah, sorry my terms are not correct. basically I am trying to send them to UPDATER-email.sent.php which just says "Your email has been sent"

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I'm just trying to get some type of "your email was sent" confirmation, whether its an alert or anything, really. I'm not married to my pseudo-redirect. Anything that words.

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I've tried window.open and window.location and window.location.href and window.location.replace.  No joy on any of them.

Comment: @nogad... php doesn't work either. I think it's because in the "both" section, I have already sent headers and produced output. I read somewhere if you have already done that you cannot send additional headers. So I figured javascript was my best bet.  I am wide open to suggestions.

Comment: the answer could be in the included files but we dont know, can you confirm the "both" block i seven called?

Comment: `er/UPDATER-email.sent.php')</s` to `er/UPDATER-email.sent.php');</s`. Could you confirm that a popup is not being brought up? And check console in the browser debugger

Comment: ahh, thank you i 7.  I'm more hacker than coder so please forgive my poor command of terms.  In Chrome I allowed popups, same behavior. calligraphydallas.com is in "allowed sites".  @Ice76 how do I "check console in the browser debugger" ?

Comment: Ok, I did a rightclick>Inspect (Chrome) and selected "Console".  It has this "This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar."

Comment: @nogad.... would you like to see the include files? They aren't very big. I would be happy to make them available if you want to see them.

Comment: sorry this is impossibly scoped to be answered here.

Comment: Yes, I figured that as well. I was hoping it might be an easy one. I appreciate everyone's efforts.